# How to display a view in Ext.Msg.prompt in Sencha touch 2?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I know that in Sencha Touch, we can display a pop up using the following code:

> new Ext.MessageBox().show({
>
> ```
>              title: 'Prompt Box',
>               message:'Welcome'            
>                 });
> ```

In my application I have created a view for changing passwords. Any since the view is too small, I dont want it to be taking entire screen. I want to display that view inside the Message Prompt. How can i accomplish this??

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Panel

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `modal: true` layout on your password change view instead of using `MessageBox`.

You can simply show this view (which will look like a popup).

Answer (score 0):

this Can do the trick..

All the best.

```
Ext.create('APP.view.Dialog', {
            msg: "Change Password </br>",
              items: [  {
                              xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'password1',
                        fieldLabel: 'location'
                          handler: function() {
                var value1 = document.getElementById('textInput1').value;
//validate 
                   // 
                }
                    },
{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'password2',
                        fieldLabel: 'location'
                          handler: function() {
                var value1 = document.getElementById('textInput1').value;
//validate 
                   // 
                }
                    }],
        buttons: [
                           {
                ui: 'red',
                text: "Change Password",
                handler: function() {
                this.getParent().hide();
                   // 
                }
            }
        ]
    }).show();
```